# MapKit: Is There A Guide on Getting The Marker Location Precise?

Tags: ios, location, mapkit, marker

OK. I don't see the answer in the list above, so I'll ask.
I'm really hoping that the answer is simple, and I'm being oblivious.

I have a marker asset that is a marker with a shadow. It's a PNG that is 37 pixels wide, and 40 pixels high.

It has a shadow image (like the default pin), and the "point" (where the location is, exactly), is on the bottom of the marker image, at (from left, top) 11, 40.

Now, according to [the MapKit centerOffset docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207), I should simply make centerOffset the delta from 18, 20, which should be -7, 20.

However, that doesn't seem to be working for me. My markers stubbornly stay centered horizontally. The vertical position seems OK.

I know that I must be doing something really stupid, can someone enlighten this poor idiot on the proper positioning of a marker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sample code for Map Callouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Listings/MapViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746-MapViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10) has a custom pin view which is offset.